# Getting specific information in a pdf with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, pdf

On larger scale I'm trying to get a large amount of contracts from an api, and those contracts contain pdf-files that contain the details of the contracts.
After i fetch these files, I'm using the 'pdf-parse' (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-parse) node.js library to read the text of the pdf's.

And now to my question: How do i manage to read certain values out of those files?
For example at the beginning of the pdf, there should be a introduction to the two parties of the contract. I would like to get the name and the email of the signing party, its formatted  like this, almost at the beginning of the pdf.
The attribute names being even, and the information made start at a even point.

```
Name          Mark Jackson 
Address       Winston Street 13 
Email         Mark@Jackson@email.com 
Etc...        ABCD...
```

What kind of method would get me these, and only these attributes of the contract?

Comment: I can tell you, but I need a full string without any (bunch of spaces). If there are any new line characters in there or spaces, i need to know

Comment: Sorry, posting the message messed up my formatting. I will be able to post an actual mock up contract by tomorrow if that is needed to help me, but really anything that would help me get started is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

so assuming string a

```
a = `Name          Mark Jackson 
Address       Winston Street 13 
Email         Mark@Jackson@email.com 
Etc...        ABCD...
`;
```

you can easily extract your name and email like this:

```
const name = a.match(/Name\s+(.*?)\n/, 'm')[1].trim();
const email = a.match(/Email\s+(.*?)\n/, 'm')[1].trim();
```

[image]